# Custom vibration patterns for notification types

Tags: notifications, vibration

I'd like to set different vibration patters for different notification types.

For example something like: 2 short buzzes for a private Whatsapp message, 2 long ones for a group message, long and short for calendar, etc. I can set custom sounds for each of these in settings, but vibrations can only be turned on or off. Is there some way to add custom vibration functionality to this?

To be clear I'm not looking for contact specific vibrations, though it would be a nice addition.

I'm using a rooted device running lineage 17.1 btw.

Comment: As an Android app developer, I believe that is not possible unless the app itself implements something like that. You do not have any system settings for this feature.

Comment: @WrichikBasu I was afraid that would be the answer. Sad since it seems like such an obvious feature to have.